# jQuery not adding class in firefox browser but works in Chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have a table within collapsible region.

Parent Region = Collapsible region (selector "`#R3510898223269632515 .t-Region-header`")
Child Region = Table (selector "`#R3510898223269632515`")

I have below jQuery to add class to Parent Region based on condition from child region

```
//Find fa-check class from child region    
$('#R3510898223269632515').filter(function(){
        return $(this).has('.fa-check').length > 0
    }).each(function(){
//If fa-check is found in child region, then add class to Parent region
        $('#R3510898223269632515 .t-Region-header').addClass('mybordergreen');
    });
```

Above code working fine in chrome browser but not working on firefox. I tried to replace

```
return $(this).has('.fa-check').length > 0
```

with

```
return $(document).has('.fa-check').length > 0
```

but still not working on firefox. Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Richa

Comment: Why are you using `.each()` but not referencing the element of the iteration?

Comment: Your code makes very little sense. An ID selector returns just one element, so using `.filter()` is strange -- it either returns that element or nothing. Then using `.each()` is strange if it's either zero or one element.

Comment: Can you show your HTML and what the intended result is supposed to be?

Comment: how can you filter a single element?  What type of element can have `.fa-check` applied to it?  Relevant HTML, and some additional context would be helpful.

Comment: As far as I can tell `$('#R3510898223269632515').has('.fa-check').find('.t-Region-header').addClass('mybordergreen');` should be what you are trying to do in a reduced form.

Comment: I will provide html in a while. Thanks

Comment: sorry if my question was vague. Am new to jQuery and the code I have is referenced by searching from internet and modified to my needs

Comment: here's the updated fiddle[link](https://jsfiddle.net/4azy0k8b/1/) with html and css. I grabbed those from chrome developer tools.

Comment: All am trying to do is: If Status Icon column from the table has class of fa-check then add class called `mybordergreen` if it has class of fa-remove then add class called `myborderred` to parent header region with label "Info based on ID: 12345"

Comment: Imported font awesome cdn to jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4azy0k8b/15/). Appreciate any help. Thanks, Richa

Comment: The statement in my previous comment works fine in your fiddle, provided you make a css rule for the class so you can see the change.

Comment: Thank @Taplar. I tried the code you provided. Its working fine in Chrome browser but its not working in Mozilla firefox